# Shared folder between Win7 (host) and Ubuntu (guest)

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I'm currently setting up my development envirnonment. I'm used to code (web stuff) on mac. Since I don't have any mac private and would liek to use Win7 I thought to just set up an VM.

My VM is working and i can access it. I enabled the brdiged network settings so my guest OS is recognized in my network.

Since I want to use my editors and software on Win7 to code on Ubuntu, I need so do some kind of folder mapping/sharing. Whats the best approach?

I've read quite a lot and people told me I should use Samba or create an shared folder.

So what's better and wheres the difference between using Samba and a shared folder?

Coudln't get the shared fodler one working yet, asking myself how it should even work. Does VirtualBox do something like Samba here?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of VirtualBox's "shared folder" feature once you install "Guest additions" on the guest.

On how to mount a "shared folder" in the Ubuntu guest, open up Virtualbox help, navigate to Guest Aditions-> shared folder -> manual mounting.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the Samba route performs better than the shared folder route, though involves much more setup. If performance is an issue, go Samba.

The shared folder is easier, and if all you want to do is occasionally copy files into it works well enough.

Comment: Due to the performance argument, I chosed samba. Atm i just set it up y adding the following to the smb.conf and using the bridget network settings of virtualbox to make my vm avalable in the network. http://pastebin.com/90xqP82H It works, but is it really done well? Somehow, I think it's not very well made. I got it from an Tutorial. Thanks